# What does "それ以前に天然入ってない?" mean?

Tags: meaning, words

[image]

In particular, I want to know what "入ってない" means here, as well as the meaning of the sentence on a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

～入ってる means that someone is "in" a particular state, or indicating/expressing someone's personality. So, in this case, it's latter: this scene is about him asking "*He(高坂くん)'s a little "天然", isn't he?*" to other people.

The meaning of the word "天然" is: People who are a little goofy, but have a charming or gentle kind of vibe tend to be called "天然".

So, while I don't know who's the 高坂くん is, but I suspect that he's a goofy guy.

Comment: In this particular usage, I would understand that 天然（要素） is in 高坂くん, not the other way around.

Comment: @aguijonazo Uh, that's what I meant... I thought it's obvious since that girl instantly affirmed it, it indicates that 高坂くん is 天然. Or did I write it wrong? I honestly don't know if I did or not.

Comment: That was in reference to this interpretation of yours: *someone is "in" a particular state/personality*. By that, the sentence would mean 高坂くん, as the subject, is in the state of 天然 as in, say, `ゾーン入ってる`.

Comment: @aguijonazo Ah, now I see it. Thanks for that, I rewrote it. I think it's a little clearer now, what do you think?